# Zip File download using swagger 2.6.1 and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui, spring-rest

I am trying to zip the files and return the zip in the response using swagger 2.6.1 and spring boot and spring security using X-security-token.

But the file that is getting downloaded from the swagger is in BLOB format and not able to open that file. Please refer the code snippet below -

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong

```
   @RequestMapping("/zipFile2")
   public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadZipFile() {
      Map<String, String> fileNameAndValueMap = new HashMap<>();
      fileNameAndValueMap.put("File1", "{\"name\":\"XYZ\",\"salary\":22}");
      fileNameAndValueMap.put("File2", "{\"name\":\"ABC\",\"salary\":44}");
      //try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
         ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
         for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fileNameAndValueMap.entrySet()) {
            ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(entry.getKey() + "." + "json");
            e.setSize(entry.getValue().length());
            e.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(e);
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(entry.getValue().getBytes());
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, zipOutputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
         }
         zipOutputStream.close();
         //byte[] zipBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

      } catch (Exception e) {
      }

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=JSONSearchResultsData-" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date()) + ".zip");
      //headers.add("attachment","JSONSearchResultsData-" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date()) + ".zip");
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "origin, content-type, accept");
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");

      headers.add(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "no-cache");
      return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length)
            //.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=JSONSearchResultsData-" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date()) + ".zip")
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
            .body(new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())));
   }
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: no error message, I am getting file in blob data not zip and it is not opening

Comment: What do you mean with *in blob data*? What content type is shown?

Comment: this is what the file I am receiving with no format -application_zip_blob_http_localhost_8080_a2c139f5-9c0c-4f41-8103-d7d9. When I will try to open it, as it is not of any desired format it is not opening